# UITextField and UITableViews... Am I doing this correctly? If not, what is the best way?

Tags: iphone

I have an array of folders.  Each folder is listed as a table view row.

When I display my table, I populate it with a set of textfields on the left hand side of the row (i want the user to be able to edit them) and a set of switches (on/off) on the right hand side of the row.

All is working well, you can touch the textfield and the keyboard appears.  You can changed the values of the switch each time also.

The problem I'm having is knowing which text field has been changed so that I can update my array ready to save the values.

I'm using..

```
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

and...

```
-(void)textFieldDone:(UITextField *)textField
```

The problem is that the textField object does not contain any unique information about it in the textFieldDone selector.  I've tried setting

```
[textField setTag:rowNumber];
```

But it doesn't show as tag is not part of the textField object.

Anyone any ideas on the best way of doing this?  Surely there must be lots of applications that have have textfields in table rows that you can switch between?

Or maybe I'm missing something here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually 'tag' is part of the UITextField as it is inherited from UIView.

Maybe I can suggest a different approach. Use your table view to display the data with a checkmark in the accessory view if the boolean value you are representing with a switch currently is set to YES. When the user taps that row, push a new view controller that contains a text field and a switch that the user can edit.

Is there an application you've seen that uses the UI method your attempting with the text field and switch in a table cell?

Keep in mind that you are probably reusing table cells, which is what you're supposed to do, however you may not be setting the tag on subsequent uses of that cell. Just guessing here.

Comment: Once I'd written this question, I began thinking about the best way to do this.  I think I've been trying hard to be clever and make it easier for the user which I should have been sticking to existing UX protocols.

When I said the "tag" isn't part of the UITextField, i meant upon inspection in the debugger or an NSLog(@"%@", textField.tag) it doesn't exist.

Will see if there is a better way to code this...

Thanks for your help and support :)